# error when calling operator inside FUNCTION const

Tags: c++, constants, operator-keyword

now i am stumbling with c++ code problem.

i made a simple structure 'Vector3' in that i defined the operator+.
and when i use that operator inside const function, it show a red line.

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3 operator+ (const Vector3 v) {
        return Vector3(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z);
    };
    Vector3(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};
};

// and i use it inside some const function
struct SomeST {
  Vector3 a,b;

  Vector3 Function() const
  {
     return a + b; // error
  }
};
```

and if i delete the const from function, it works!
so it would be amazing if someone can explain what's going on under the hood.
thanks.

Comment: Your `operator+()` should also be const (`Vector3 operator+ (const Vector3 v) const`), otherwise the compiler doesn't think it is.

Comment: What is a `structure`?

Comment: @L.F. Have edited to use `struct` and to add a constructor.

Comment: @KaenbyouRin please do not change the contents of a question like you did, only the OP can change its behavior

Comment: @bruno copy that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function

```
Vector3 Function() const
```

is const. Which means, that `this` is const inside the function. Which in turn means both `a` and `b` are const. `a + b` syntax is fancy way for writing `a.operator + (b)` (call `operator +` method on object `a` with argument `b`). Now `a` is const, so `a.operator +` method must also be const. Since you've not supplied such operator (the operator you've written is not const) your compiler highlights this as error and if you try to compile it, you will get const based error.

You need to suply `operator + (...) const`, which in this exact case means you need to add `const` keyword to definition:

```
Vector3 operator+ (const Vector3 v) const { ... }
```